# How do I get a query button to repeat post while a button is held down?

Tags: jquery, post, arduino

I'm using POSTs to send commands to an arduino.  I want the up command to be repeated while the button is held down.  Here is what I'm trying...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../templates/mainkibblynibblytemplate/css/kibbly-jquery.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timeout, clicker = $('#upbutton');

        clicker.mousedown(function () {
                          timeout = setInterval(function () {
                                                $.post('http://192.168.1.77:8888/', {
                                                       text: 'up'
                                                       });
                                                }, 500);

                          return false;
                          });

        $(document).mouseup(function () {
                            clearInterval(timeout);
                            return false;
                            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="upbutton">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you having a problem or something?

Comment: That looks like it should work fine (though an ajax request every half a second might be a lot). What are you seeing instead?

Comment: I've edited above to include all the html.  It just isn't posting when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `onkeydown` event in JavaScript. On the onkeydown event, you can loop through the times you result you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you have to handler the event mouseup to a button and remove the "return false"

like this:

```
clicker.mousedown(function () {
   timeout = setInterval(function () {
                 $.post('http://192.168.1.77:8888/', {
                       text: 'up'
                 });
              }, 500);
});

clicker.mouseup(function () {
    clearInterval(timeout);
 });
```

Comment: It still isn't posting.

Comment: you have to look with firebug , if the post appear in console tab.
if dont, the problem is the post code:                  $.post('http://192.168.1.77:8888/', {
                       text: 'up'
                 });